# Prove for every integer $n$ that there exist two integers $a$ and $b$ of opposite parity such that $an+b$ is an odd integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

_solution:  prove by cases.

Case 1: **n** is odd. That is **n = 2k + 1**

- Case 1.1: **a** is odd and **b** is even. That is **a = 2m + 1** and **b = 2n**
  So **(2k+1)(2m+1)+2n = 4km+2k+2m+1+2n = 2(2km+k+m+n)+1** is odd.
- Case 1.2: **a** is even and **b** is odd. That is **a = 2m** and **b = 2n + 1**
  So **(2k+1)(2m)+2n+1 = 4km+2m+2n+1 = 2(2km+m+n)+1** is odd.

Case 2: **n** is even. That is **n = 2k**

- Case 2.1: **a** is odd and **b** is even. That is **a = 2m + 1** and **b = 2n**
  So **(2k)(2m+1)+2n = 4km+2k+2n = 2(2km+k+n)** is even.
- Case 2.2: **a** is even and **b** is odd. That is **a = 2m** and **b = 2n + 1**
  So **(2k)(2m)+2n+1 = 4km+2n+1 = 2(2km+n)+1** is odd.

_My question: does case 2.1 disprove the statement or have I made a mistake in my proof?!

Comment: The question is about **existence**. So it is enough to show that there is something which can do the job. In your proof: case1.1 and case 2.2 are enough. A simpler way could be to take $a=1$ and $b=2$ when $n$ is odd and take $a=2, b=1$, when $n$ is even. This shows there exists integers of opposite parity that can do the job.

Comment: No, case 2.1 does not disprove the statement. You’ve already shown that for even $n$ there exist $a, b$ such that $an+b$ is odd, through case 2.2.

Comment: We should pay more attention to what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Why do you need cases? Why can't you just take $a=2$ and $b=1$?

Comment: @bof Because I'm a newbie

Comment: As you correctly state, we should pay more attention to what we are trying to prove. What we are trying to prove is "one of case $2.1$ or case $2.2$ work for case $2$".

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the work you need to do to prove this a lot by using the rules that:

- even * even = even
- even * odd = odd
- odd * even = odd
- odd * odd = even

and

- even + even = even
- even + odd = odd
- odd + even = odd
- odd + odd = even

then you can prove this by cases:

- If n is even then odd * even + even = odd
- If n is odd then even * odd + even = odd